# Google Site Kit Plugin has been copied to multiple sites, so Analytics information is inaccurate

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, flywheel

My company manages several websites for clients. We build Wordpress sites and manage them all on Flywheel. Whenever we make a new website, we typically duplicate an existing site so that we can reuse some general settings. I recently found out that the Google Site Kit plugin has been getting duplicated, along with its existing settings, so that multiple separate websites have been pointing to the same google analytics account. Because they are all pointing to the same account, the Google Analytics account is just tracking slugs, thinking all traffic is coming from the same base url. Now all traffic on common pages, such as Home, Contact, and About are being clumped together, highly inflating the numbers of what traffic would be on any one of the sites. Is there a way to separate the data by base url, so I could see accurate data for each site?

Comment: Disconnect the account and rAuth with the correct account. It doesn't look like an issue, you just copied all the data which include analytic ID as well, you either change it manually or use disconnect and reconnect option(if that is a thing on that plugin)

Comment: I have reauthenticated all the sites, however, I don't see a way to transfer the data in Google Analytics. Because it looks like GA wasn't tracking which base url data was coming from, just the slugs of pages, because technically all the sites were connected to the same view in GA.

Answer (score 0):

In that case what you'll need to do on the sites with the same property is revisit the Site Kit settings and connect to the correct Google Analytics property (and Tag Manager / AdSense if applicable).

Note also that if your site URL changes Site Kit does recognize this, asking users to connect once more on the new domain. If you then connect on the new site you'll need to change the connected Google Analytics property.

Going forward, before you duplicate a site that has Site Kit active you can disconnect the Google Analytics, AdSense and Tag Manager modules before duplicating, before connecting once more after copying. Alternatively you can reset Site Kit before duplicating. Resetting will mean you'll need to connect all services once more (after duplicating).

Hopefully the above helps.